# Program in C randomly crashes when I use free()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This program is supposed to allow the user to type in as many variables as they would like (which is stored in an array). Once the user types in "-999", the program will stop filling the array, find the largest number in the array and end. However, when I input some test numbers into the program, it will successfully end at times, but other times it will just decide to crash.

For example, I could type in:

```
100 (return) 200 (return) 300 (return) 400 (return) -999 (return)
```

and it will crash.

Then I'll type in:

```
10 (return) 20 (return) 30 (return) 40 (return) -999 (return)
```

and it will run successfully. Then if I type what I typed originally it will work and won't crash. And I'll even repeat this test and it won't replicate the same results.

I'm totally confused and lost, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fillArray(int *a);
int largestElement(int *a);

int i = 0;

int main()
{
    int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

    fillArray(array);

    printf("The largest element in 'array' is: %d\n", largestElement(array));

    //Program randomly crashes right here sometimes, not sure why.
    printf("Right before free function...\n");
    free(array);
    printf("Successfully freed!\n");

    return 0;
}

void fillArray (int *a)
{
    int userInput = 0;
    printf("Type in a list of numbers terminated by a -999:\n");

    while(userInput != -999)
    {
        //*a = realloc(a, (i+1) * sizeof(int));

        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        a[i] = userInput;
        i++;
    }
}

int largestElement(int *a)
{
    int j;
    int largest = a[0];

    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        if(a[j] > largest){
            largest = a[j];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: `int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));` allocates probably **4 bytes** of memory. Yet you have a loop incrementing an index, which writes to it, `a[i] = userInput; i++;`

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried to use the realloc() function, but that would just store weird numbers in my array and make it crash too.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`  for the functions: `malloc()` and `free()`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: regarding: `int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));`  This only allocates enough room for a single integer. and the posted code is not increasing that allocation (perhaps via a call to `realloc()`) so as soon as a second integer is input, the allocated memory is overflowed, resulting in undefined behavior and can (as you have seen) lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: note: when calling `realloc()` assign the returned value to a temporary variable, then check it for NULL and if not NULL then assign to the target variable.   Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the pointer to the currently allocated memory is lost, resulting in a memory leak and accessing anything off that NULL pointer will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the crash on `free` is because you only allocate space for a single `int`, but you copy values into `a` as if it's an array with multiple values.  Writing past the end of allocated memory like that invokes undefined behavior.

The call to `realloc` you have commented out isn't quite doing what you want:

```
*a = realloc(a, (i+1) * sizeof(int));
```

The expression `*a` is of type `int`, do it doesn't make sense to assign a pointer back to it.  Because `realloc` can move the memory that was originally allocated, you need to pass the *address* of `array` in main so that it can be modified in the calling function.

So change `fillArray` to take a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void fillArray (int **a)
{
    int userInput = 0;
    printf("Type in a list of numbers terminated by a -999:\n");

    while(userInput != -999)
    {
        *a = realloc(*a, (i+1) * sizeof(int));

        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        (*a)[i] = userInput;
        i++;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
fillArray(&array);
```

Comment: the function: `realloc()` may return NULL, so assign to a temporary pointer, check for NULL as a reason to cleanup and exit the program.  Otherwise, if not NULL, then assign to the target variable via `*a = temp;`